# Get the value of some data in the last row of a specified column

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google form that is linked to a spreadsheet that populates every time the form gets submitted. I want to get data from the last row that is populated. When I attempt to debug the function, it only shows the number of the last row and not it's contents.

```
//Section J: Send email to DFAB team
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Response Data');
var last_entry = sheet1.getLastRow();
var last_dewar = last_entry.getValue();
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please provide your sample code so we can better help you?

Comment: If you wish to get the data that is associated with the form submission the best way is through  the event object.  Typically we use e to hold the event object so e.values will the the same array that is populated into the last line of the sheet.  If you wish to know the sheet and row the. e.range.getSheet().getName() provides the name of the sheet and e.range.getRow() provides the row number.

Comment: I have updated my question with an image of the code that I have put together.

Comment: We don't really like to get code in images please learn how to [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and post it as text into your question.  The problem with using the last line is if you get multiple submissions at the same time then that last line may not be the line that is associated with the current submission.

Comment: Hello @Ademola, welcome to this community. I need further details about your case. Could you provide more information? Like do you want to get the data that just submitted or do you just want to get the last data in your spreadsheet? Thank you.

Comment: I'm asking this because these 2 cases have their own way of solution. @Ademola

Answer (score 0):

First I'm not sure how your are running the script but if you want to do it the way you have shown you should know `getLastRow()` returns the number of the last row in a sheet.  `getValue()` is a method of a Range object so it should throw an error.  Instead try this.

```
//Section J: Send email to DFAB team
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Response Data');
var last_dewar = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues()
```

If you use an `onFormSubmit(e)` trigger then the information submitted is in the `e.values` property of the event object as mentioned by @Cooper.

References

- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thank you I can now see the values when I debug the program.  With this I want to make a function to create a timestamp whenever a particular keyword is mentioned in the array? For example, if the last line included the word "Item 1" create a timestamp when it was populated in the sheet. Then if the next last line contains the word, "Item 2" create a timestamp when is was populated in the sheet.

Comment: If its a form response the date and time of the submittal should be included in the row.